# PHP - Not redirecting on successfull login

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is a strange problem

When I go onto `login.php` and enter my login details on my testing server I get redirected to `admin.php` page as I should,

However when I uploaded my files to my hosting server and I go to `login.php` and enter my login details NOTHING happens, I mean nothing the page just reloads. I should get redirected to `admin.php` page like I do when I test my site on localhost, but on webserver nothing happens

Does anyone have any idea why this is?

Here is my code:

```
//Open SQL connection
include 'connect.php';
//Check if user has entered Data yet
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
//Get values from username and password user entered into form field
    $uname = $_POST['name'];
    $pword = $_POST['pword'];
//Get username and password from database   
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT `username`, `password` 
                            FROM player_info
                            WHERE `position` = "coach" ') or die (mysql_error());   
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $username = $row['username'];
            $password = $row['password'];       
        }
//Check if username and password entered matched the username and password stored in the database
            if($uname != $username  || $pword != $password)
            {
            echo '<center><p style="color:red">Username and Password incorrect. Please try again</center>';
            }
                    
//if username and password match redirect to admin page         
                else if($uname = $username && $pword == $password)
                {
                            echo("<script>location.href ='admin.php'</script>");
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION[$pword];
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;  
                }
            }
            echo'<ul>';
            echo'<li><a href="login.txt"><b>Source Code</a>';
            echo'</ul>';        
//Login Form    
        echo'<form name="test" action="" method="post">';
                echo'<div align="center">';
                echo '<form name="login" method="post" action="">';
                echo'<input type="text" name="name">'; echo'<input type="password" name="pword">';
                echo '<input type="submit" name="submit">';
        echo '</form>';
echo '<h2>Welcome to the Scoregasims rugby club</h2>';
echo '<img src="images/logo.jpg">';
echo'</div>';

echo'
</body>
</html>';
?>
```

P.S I know this code is not safe from sqlinjections but I am not learning about that yet.

Comment: php uses header() for redirection.

Comment: Is the JavaScript that you use for redirection actually received by the browser (check the "View Source" menu item)? Are there errors displayed in the error console of the browser?

Comment: I have tried doing that allready, same result

Comment: Does the correct username and password actually exist in the database with the same credentials you're submitting in the login form?

Answer (score 1):

User header like :

```
header("location:admin.php") instead of js below 
 echo("<script>location.href ='admin.php'</script>");
```

You can also use html redirection for  this purpose like this :

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=admin.php'>";
```

Comment: what the issue you got while using header function ?

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/03/11433803/html/login.php:10) in /home/content/03/11433803/html/login.php on line 40

Answer (score 0):

please check in the section:

```
else if($uname = $username && $pword == $password)
{
echo("<script>location.href ='admin.php'</script>");
session_start();
$_SESSION[$pword];
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;  
}
```

You echoed a redirection in the above code. If you would like to redirect after successful login and hold the value into session to `admin.php` , just write the line underneath of this line `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;` as

```
else if($uname = $username && $pword == $password)
{        
$_SESSION[$pword];
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;  
echo("<script>location.href ='admin.php'</script>");
}
```

And FYI you must write `session_start();` at the top of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Stop "echo'ing" every line of HTML - it's going to be impossible for you to write and debug HTML.

```
 <?php
      some code...
      ... more code...
    ?>
      <div>Hello</div>
      <div><?php echo $user_name; ?></div>
    <?php ...more code... ?>
```

Your thing is broken becasue you need to specify what the script is in your  tag. Do `<script type="text/javascript">js code here</script>`.

Finally, don't echo out js for this. Just do this PHP code: 
`header(Location: /admin.php);`

Comment: If I use header(Location: /admin.php) I get this error Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/03/11433803/html/login.php:10) in /home/content/03/11433803/html/login.php on line 40

Comment: as part of this portfolio project we are required to ECHO each and every line of HTML ridiculous I know

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your code - `else if($uname = $username && $pword == $password)` .. You were not checking the `$username` against any record as the case should be. I'm sure you meant to **use == rather** than **just =**

Comment: he means $uname == $username. But that won't change from local to production so it's not the cause of your error - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

First : You have specified two forms. One inside another.

Second : Proper usage of header tag should be done.

P.S : You need not echo each and every html. You can simply do as follows.

I have modified your answer a bit  :

```
<?php
ob_start();
//Open SQL connection
include('connect.php');
//Check if user has entered Data yet
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){   
    //Get values from username and password user entered into form field
    $uname = $_POST['name'];
    $pword = $_POST['pword'];
    //Get username and password from database   
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT `username`, `password` FROM player_info WHERE `position` = "coach" ') or die (mysql_error());   
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $username = $row['username'];
        $password = $row['password'];       
    }
    //Check if username and password entered matched the username and password stored in the database
    if($uname != $username  || $pword != $password){
    echo '<center><p style="color:red">Username and Password incorrect. Please try again</center>';
    }
    //if username and password match redirect to admin page         
    else if($uname = $username && $pword == $password){
        // echo("<script>location.href ='admin.php'</script>");
        session_start();
        $_SESSION[$pword];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;  
        header("Location:admin.php");
    }
}

?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="login.txt"><b>Source Code</b></a>        
    </li>
</ul>      
<!-- Login Form     -->
<div align="center">
    <form name="login" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="name">    
        <input type="password" name="pword">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    <h2>Welcome to the Scoregasims rugby club</h2>
    <img src="images/logo.jpg">';
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your answer as part of this portfolio project we are required to ECHO each and every line of HTML ridiculous I know

Comment: Did u try removing the two forms and using header() along with ob_start() at top?

Answer (score 0):

in else if condition,

```
 else if($uname = $username && $pword == $password)
```

should be like

```
else if($uname == $username && $pword == $password) // equal to symbol is missed
```

Section should be,

```
   else if($uname == $username && $pword == $password)
            {
                session_start();                    
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;  
                $_SESSION['pword'] = $pword;  
                echo ("<script>window.location.href ='admin.php';</script>");

            }
```